# Doxygen's page across multiple comments block

Tags: c, doxygen

In order to write documentation for my Catch tests, I want to do a thing such as :

```
/// \page TEST_CALCULATOR Test Calculator
/// Testing is so cool... !
SCENARIO("Compute things...") {
    /// Test a simple formula :
    /// \code
    WHEN("23 2 + 3 +") {
       // here is the tested code
    }
    /// \endcode
}
```

The idea is to have a compiling source file and a documentation with code samples tied up to source implementation.

The point is, Doxygen does not seem to create an entire page for this. The generated page only contains "Testing is so cool... !".
Any idea on how to do a such thing ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: \page command stops at the end of its comment blocks, which is not the behavior I want. The rest is working well except it is displayed only in the documentation of the source file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'example' tag.

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdexample

Comment: Yes, but it includes the whole file's content. Actually, I would like to write as many sections as scenarios and all in the same file (to avoid mis-correlations between source and documentations).